# Converting tabbed/indented Python string into HTML list output

Tags: python, html, css, python-2.7

I have the following string as an example:

```
>>> a
'The Distribution as follows:\n\t\t- 71% as follows:\n\t\t\tfirst, to A;\n\t\t\tsecond, to B;\n\t\t\tthird, to C, D, and E as follows:\n\t\t\t\t- 15% to C\n\t\t\t\t- 85% to D and E.\n\t\t- 29% to F.'
>>> print a
The Distribution as follows:
    - 71% as follows:
        first, to A;
        second, to B;
        third, to C, D, and E as follows:
            - 15% to C
            - 85% to D and E.
    - 29% to F.
```

I need to convert such a string into HTML output that would look like this:

```
<span style="display:block; font: 13px 'Times New Roman'">The Distribution as follows:<br>
<ul style="display:block; list-style-type:none; line-height: 17px; font: 13px 'Times New Roman';">
    <li>- 71% as follows:</li>
    <ul style="display:block; list-style-type:none; line-height: 17px; font: 13px 'Times New Roman';"> 
        <li>first, to A;</li>
        <li>second, to B;</li>
        <li>third, to C, D, and E as follows:</li>
        <ul style="display:block; list-style-type:none; line-height: 17px; font: 13px 'Times New Roman';">
            <li>- 15% to C</li>
            <li>- 85% to D and E.</li>
        </ul>
     </ul>
     <li>- 29% to F.</li>
     </ul>
</span>
```

CSS will be defined separately, this is the interim solution for testing.  In addition, I need to replace dashes with solid bullet points at the second level, and with hollow bullet points at the third level, and so on, if they are tiered.  For example:

```
- X% as follows:
    * Y% as follows:
        o Z% as follows:
            - A% as follows:
```

I have this iteration that used to work when I had each line wrapped in `<p>` tags with dynamic `left-padding`; however, I need to convert all my `<p>` tags, where such list items need to have HTML list elements.  It doesn't work in some cases, e.g. the example above, where the 29% line is part of the first indent (my code indents it with the previous line since it brute-writes `</ul>` at the end.  It also doesn't address my dash/solid bullet/hollow bullet at all.

```
        if '\t' in a:
            a= a.replace('\n', '<br>', 1)
            a= a.replace('\n', '</li>')
            tabs = get_tabs(gp_ln)
            tabs.sort(reverse=True)
            for tab in tabs:
                a= a.replace(tab, '\n<ul style="display:block; list-style-type:none; line-height: 17px; '
                                           'font: 13px \'Times New Roman\';">\n<li>', 1)
                a= a.replace(tab, '\n<li>')

            a+= '</li>'
            a+= '</ul>' * len(tabs) + '\n'
```

As I'm working through all the edge cases, I can't help but wonder if there's a far easier solution.  I don't know much about HTML either, so open to all suggestions.  I would rather not use external (non built-in) Python libraries as well.